# Who was the first to prove that the automorphism group of a finite field is cyclic and is generated by the Frobenius automorphism?

Tags: nt.number-theory, ho.history-overview, galois-theory, finite-fields, automorphism-groups

$\DeclareMathOperator\Aut{Aut}$It is well-known that the automorphism group $\Aut(F)$ of a finite field $F$ of characteristic $p$ is cyclic of order $n$ where $|F|=p^n$. Moreover, the cyclic group $\Aut(F)$ is generated by the [Frobenius automorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_endomorphism) $\phi:F\to F$, $\phi:x\mapsto x^p$.

> **Question 1:** Who was the first to prove this result and when? (Galois, Jordan, Frobenius, Burnside, Moore, Artin?)

I have found the paper ["A history of Galois fields"](https://hal.science/hal-00786662/document) by Frederic Brechenmacher but unfortunately could not locate a precise answer to my question (maybe I have overlooked it, because the paper is rather long). Also a more general question on the entire history of Galois theory was asked [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/26811/61536), but also without precise answers.

Known proofs of the cyclicity of the automorphism group of a finite field use another classical result (saying that the multiplicative group of a finite field is cyclic). Many proofs of this classical result (including [my own proof](https://mathoverflow.net/a/466840/61536)) are collected in this [MO-post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/54735/61536). Now the same historical question arises:

> **Question 2:** Who was the first to prove that the multiplicative group of a finite field is cyclic? (Galois, Jordan, Frobenius, Burnside, Moore?)